# Did this dd command run too fast?

Tags: usb, dd, usb-drive, file-copy, disk-image

Usually people want to speed `dd` up but I want to slow it down, because I think there is something fishy going on with its speed.

```
sudo dd if=hannah-montana-linux-amd64.iso of=/dev/sdb1 bs=512k
```

> 5988+0 records in
>
> 5988+0 records out
>
> 3139436544 bytes (3.1 GB, 2.9 GiB) copied, 8.703 s, 361 MB/s

This is a USB 2.0 stick. How is this even posible? Did something go wrong?

Edit: This is not a duplicate because my question specifically asks whether the execution was successful or something went wrong. Additionally, if something did indeed go wrong I would like to know how to prevent this and how to use the command *correctly*.

Comment: Possibly buffering. It may take a bit of time to properly eject the drive?

Comment: Definitively buffering.

Comment: You sure you wanted it on a partition rather than the device itself...?

Comment: @Kusalananda @Rui How can I know when it's done?  `progress` doesn't help either.

Comment: @frostschutz Why does that matter? Does dd do something differently?

Comment: I added an answer on the other question with a specific example - i.e. a full command, not just "use this option".  It should show "how to prevent this".  IMO the existing answer already provided the explanation about what was going on, "how it is even possible".  I would say it confirms the assumption in the linked question that this is "technically" not an error, it is just not what the vast majority of people actually want when they use `dd`.

Comment: What happen if you run "eject /dev/sdb" after that ... do the system hangs and usb stick start to blink? If so, that's absolutely normal, the information was saved on RAM memory to speed - up (buffering), when you call eject you will force that information to really be recorded on the usb stick. ;-)